# File not found: /index.cfm

Tags: apache, coldfusion

I'm having this weird issue where ColdFusion is not finding any .cfm files. I'm getting `File not found: /index.cfm` even though it is there. I've tested to see if I could put in the exact path... still not finding it. I tested .html pages and that works.

I checked:

- File/Folder Permissions
- Apache Config
- Restarted ColdFusion
- ColdFusion is running

Also, I dont think Apache is the issue but here is the vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName foo.bar.net
DocumentRoot "C:/websites/error"
ErrorLog "logs/error500.log"
CustomLog "logs/error500.log" common
<Directory "C:\websites\error">
   AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

ColdFusion Connector:

```
# Load mod_jk module
LoadModule    jk_module  "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\mod_jk.so"
# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\workers.properties"
JkMountFile "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\uriworkermap.properties"
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\mod_jk.log"
# custom environment variables
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_URL
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_REMOTE_HOST
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_PATH
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_HTTP_ACCEPT
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_HTTP_USER_AGENT
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_REMOTE_ADDR
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_SERVER_NAME
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_SERVER_SOFTWARE
# Where to put jk shared memory
JkShmFile "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\jk_shm"
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel info
# Select the timestamp log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
AddHandler jakarta-servlet .cfm .cfml .cfc .cfr .cfswf
DirectoryIndex index.cfm
#Alias /CFIDE "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE"
#<Directory "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE">
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#AllowOverride None
#Order allow,deny
#Allow from all
#</Directory>

# /CFIDE/scripts should be available globally
Alias /CFIDE/scripts "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts"
<Directory "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Files ~ ".hbmxml$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: lets see the CF connector portion of the Apache config

Comment: Do you need the project code for this Sean? Kidding. I'll update the question.

Comment: What happens if you create a test.cfm and access it directly, as http://ip:port/test.cfm

Comment: It will say that test.cfm is not found

Comment: To clarify what Amit is saying, create the file `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\test.cfm` and browse to `http://localhost:8500/test.cfm` (thus bypassing Apache entirely) - if that doesn't work then it's a CF error and nothing to do with Apache/connectors. (If it does work, then the issue is probably misconfiguration on the Apache/mod_jk side.)

Comment: Also, if you have debugging on with cgi variables, the CF error message will be including `CF_TEMPLATE_PATH` which should confirm the full path where it is looking for the file.

Comment: I got that Peter. Then it's a ColdFusion error. I'll check the logs. Thanks you

Comment: Just because it doesn't respond on 8500 does NOT mean that it is a CF issue.  Depending on how you installed CF, the built in web server might not be enabled.  You can check the `c:\coldfusion10\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml` file to see if the "built in" web server is enabled.